# Something wrong when I apply Derivative on a SparseArray

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays, calculus-and-analysis

**Bug introduced in v5.0 or earlier, and persisting through v11.0.1 or later**

---

There, I create a `SparseArray` using command

```
y[t] = SparseArray[{{i_, 1} -> Subscript[y, i][t]}, {5, 1}]
```

And I want to get its third order derivative, Firstly I used `Map` to get the result

```
aa = D[#, {t, 3}] & /@ y[t] // MatrixForm
```

But the result is as follow

```
(*{{Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 1]][t]}, 
  {Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 2]][t]},
  {Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 3]][t]}, 
  {Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 4]][t]}, 
  {Derivative[1][Subscript[y, 5]][t]}}*)
```

And I know that the right result can be get by `@@@`

```
aa = D[#, {t, 3}] & @@@ y[t] // MatrixForm
```

With the result of

```
(*{Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 1]][t],
   Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 2]][t], 
   Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 3]][t], 
   Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 4]][t], 
   Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 5]][t]}*)
```

Here what I wondered is that why the first command can get a result, and the result is wrong

Here, I get another method to solve this problem. Use `Normal` to this `SparseArray`

```
y[t] = SparseArray[{{i_, 1} -> Subscript[y, i][t]}, {5, 1}] // Normal
aa = D[y[t], {t, 3}]
```

then I get the result again

```
(*{{Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 1]][t]},
 {Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 2]][t]}, 
 {Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 3]][t]},
 {Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 4]][t]}, 
 {Derivative[3][Subscript[y, 5]][t]}}*)
```

Comment: I have contacted support, [CASE:3606416]

Comment: @happyfish Thanks for reporting it. I didn't do it because I was still waiting in case anybody had a rational explanation...

Comment: @Jens bug confirmed by support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is definitely something wrong here. The alternative form of the third derivative would be to do three successive differentiations on the same object. The result in that approach is correct:

```
D[y[t], t, t, t] // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  y_1{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_2{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_3{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_4{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_5{}^{(3)}(t) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

The fact that you get a different result with `D[y[t], {t,3}]` is not consistent with this result, and I would therefore consider it a bug.

The successive differentiations work even though they still return a `SparseArray` object, so it should definitely not be necessary to unpack the `SparseArray` before doing `D`, as you're effectively doing when using `@@@`.

To show how crazy things get with this bug, here is another attempt that produces the desired result in a silly way:

```
D[D[D[y[t], {t, 3}], {t, 3}], {t, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  y_1{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_2{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_3{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_4{}^{(3)}(t) \\
>  y_5{}^{(3)}(t) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

This should of course be the ninth derivative if *Mathematica* had done it right.

Comment: Thx. This answer means (*D[y[t], t, t, t]*) and (*D[y[t], {t,3}]*) works in different ways in mathematica?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed. The version I used does the first derivative three times in a row, as in `D[D[D[y[t],t],t],t]`, and that is different from `D[y[t],{t,3}]` because in this case *Mathematica* will try to be more efficient. However, it's clearly doing this wrong.